# How to reference the fileset from another subprojects configuration in gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like something like this(notice the :sub is a reference to a subproject)

```
task deleteJars(type: Delete) {
    ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    delete ext.collection
}
task copyJars(type: Copy) { 
    from(:sub.configurations.compile) {}
    from(fixedLibDir) {}
    into genLibDir
}
copyJars.dependsOn('deleteJars')
classes.dependsOn('copyJars')
```

This doesn't compile however.  For playframework, I need to get the jars in that other projects configuration into my lib directory for playframework to startup.  How can I fix the above code?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should it be something like:

```
project(":sub").configurations.compile
```

?

Comment: As zggame mentioned, in some cases when your subproject is evaluated prior to your dependency subproject then gradle will raise an error. You can postpone evaluation by using a closure. eg: { project(":sub").configurations.compile }

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to put

```
evaluationDependsOn('sub')
```

at the beginning of your main script.  Otherwise, you will get error such as

```
 Configuration with name 'compile' not found
```

The reason is that generally the main project is compiled before the subproject and the compiler have trouble to find the configuration'compile' of the subproject.